# how to use loadingController without using promise?

Tags: promise, observable, loading, ionic4, loader

I am using Loading Controller using promise , but some loader will dismiss but sometimes it will not dismiss in Ionic 4.
How to use loading controller using observable or behaviour subject in ionic 4?

I have tried various link available on the internet and the problem is same it will not dismiss sometimes.

My Code is here:-
Loaderservice.ts

```
isLoading = false;
  constructor(private loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {}

async present(){
     this.isLoading = true;
     return await this.loadingCtrl.create({}).then(a=>{
       a.present().then(()=>{
         if(!this.isLoading){
           a.dismiss().then(()=>console.log('abort presenting'));
         }
       });
     });
   }

   async dismiss(){
     this.isLoading = false;
     return await this.loadingCtrl.dismiss().then(()=> console.log('dismissed'));
   }
```

homepage.ts

```
getHomePage() {
    this.loadingService.present();
    let variationLatestProductsPriceArray = [];
    this.homepageService.getHomePageData().subscribe(response => {
      this.homePageModel = response['data'];
      let checkAddress = this.homePageModel["address"];
      if (checkAddress == true){
        console.log("address Saved");
        localStorage.setItem('newUser', 'true');
      } else {
        console.log("address not Saved");
        localStorage.setItem('newUser', 'false');
      }
      console.log("latestProducts", this.latestProducts);
      this.bannerList = this.homePageModel["slider"];
      this.loadingService.dismiss();

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.alert.myAlertMethod("OOPS ! NO INTERNET Please check your network connection.", err.error.message, data => {
        console.log("hello alert")
      });
      this.loadingService.dismiss();
    },()=>{
      this.loadingService.dismiss();
    });
  }
```

Some time it works right and dismiss it correctly but sometime it will not dismiss.
I am looking into this problem from last 5 days.

Comment: Please update full code..

Comment: @Utpaul  please check i have updated the code

Comment: check answer and update your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re write present function:

```
  async present(){
         return await this.loadingCtrl.create({});
    }
```

modify getHomePage function like:

```
getHomePage() {
      this.loadingService.present().then(event => {
       event.present();
       -----
       event.dismiss();
     })
}
```

I think you will be helpful.

Comment: this.loadingService.then is not coming on the code, it shows error [ts] Property 'then' does not exist on type 'LoaderService'. @Utpaul

Comment: @user9483522 now check

Comment: thanks @Utpaul but can you please tell me where i am wrong or please tell me the other way using observable